# Не могу изучить темы InputStream и OutputStream

Tags: java, io

Изучаю Java, начал изучать Java I/O.

Не могу понять что за потоки? Это как Theard/Runnable? Почему так много разновидностей io  к примеру Objectio, DataIO и пр.

Помогите понять эту тему и освоить. Не против был бы статей где всё про это разжовывается, но понятным языком.

Answer (score 1):

Это потоки ввода/вывода. Используются еще в сериализации. Треды работают по другому.

Самое простое объяснение, которое я видел есть в книге "Изучаем Java" Кэти Сьерра, Берт Бэйтс. Скачать можно в вк, в разделе документы.

Потоки ввода/вывода - глава 14.

Thread страница 518.

Comment: спасиьо болшое за подсказку